# Tkinter: Adding the first cell of TreeView to a URL

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'd like it so you can highlight a row from the TreeViewer and have it appear in the URL and search. So for example you'd click Row 1 and it'd say [www.google.com/pepperoni](http://www.google.com/pepperoni)

The {*pizzaNumber*} needs to be inserted into the URL, my last attempt was hoping maybe if I did a my_tree[columns, 0] maybe it'd pull from the first row. But no.

Earlier I was asking about doing the same thing with an entry box and I was fairly close to getting the right answer but this one, I dont even have the slightest clue how to actually do it.

```
root.geometry("650x500")

my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

my_tree['columns'] = ("Topping", "Name", "---", "Notes" )


my_tree.column("#0", width=50, minwidth=25)
my_tree.column("Topping", width=100)
my_tree.column("Name", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
my_tree.column("---", width=80)
my_tree.column("Notes", width=200)

my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Topping", text="P/N", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Name", text="Name", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("---", text="Peen", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Notes", text="Notes", anchor=CENTER)


parent = [
    ["Pepperoni", "", "", ""],
    ["Pineapple", "", "", ""],
    ["Sauage", "", "", ""],
    ["Cheese", "", "", ""],
    ["Chicken", "Rib", "", ""],
]


count=0
for record in parent:
    my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text="", values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3]))
    count += 1

def openPizza():
    _lineNo_ = browser.get()
    _pizzaNumber_ = my_tree['columns']
    url = f'google.com/{_pizzaNumber_}{_lineNo_}'
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
new = 1


browser = Entry(width=15)
browser.pack()


Submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=openPizza)
Submit.pack(pady=20)
```

Comment: Try `_pizzaNumber_ = my_tree.set(my_tree.focus(), "Topping")`.

Comment: Ahhh I knew it was something .focus but I didnt think "Topping" would work. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the focus as follows works:

```
_pizzaNumber_ = my_tree.set(my_tree.focus(), "Topping")
```

(As suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570478/tkinter-adding-the-first-cell-of-treeview-to-a-url/68597791#comment121186088_68570478) by [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668).)

Comment: Please don't copy someone else's comment as your own answer, or else make it a community wiki if you think it'll really add to the discussion.

Comment: @joanis - It's not universally agreed that using somebody's comments in an answer is not OK.  See [What to do when my comment has been reposted as an answer by another user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288847) vs [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the links. The second is pretty clear that such a post should be made a community wiki, and I think that's important to do. I agree with both links you shared that it's useful to turn a comment solving the problem into an answer, and when done as a community wiki I'm happy to see that happen.

Comment: Not really sure what else to do when the answer is answered in a comment and not as an actual answer.